# Conditional background image

Tags: reactjs

I would like to display picture in the background, it works fine but my api does not always show pictures. So I would like to create a conditional that displays another picture instead. I don't know where to display my conditional, in style or in the url? I made several tests but I can't do it.

```
const bannerStyle = {
        backgroundImage: `url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.backdrop_path}")`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover"
    }
```

```
 <div style={bannerStyle}>
    ...
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an img tag to do it. You could just use a `<img src={} />` tag with a simple ternary condition.

Comment: Answers shouldn't rely on external links. Should make an edit to include the code that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your `div` write a ternary in `style`:

```
<div 
  style={ bannerStyle.backgroundImage === 'something' ? `urlA` : `urlB` }  
/>
```

Or set a background image as a default.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you're using React or NextJS kind of framework.

You can add condition to the whole link.

```
const bannerStyle = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${movie?.backdrop_path ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie?.backdrop_path}` : "Another Image Link"})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover"
    }
```

- If there is some value `movie?.backdrop_path`, then it returns path
  else it returns undefined.

You can then add bannerStyle object in style.

```
 <div style={bannerStyle}>
    ...
 </div>
```